# Set doc without operation read?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I try set data and it is working but when doing this i get response with create data and get read operation which have price. I don't want pay.

I tried find in SDK CLIENT REFERENCE but don't find.

```js
let documentRef = await firestore
  .collection('tt')
  .doc('col')
  .set({foo: 'bar'});
```

I don't want get write data but i get them.

Comment: If I may, it not clear what is your exact problem. Are you saying that you would like to have the `set()` method returning the data that was just written (without the need to fetch the document with `get()`)?

Comment: I do not want to receive a response with data when I do I put new data with `set` because it has a price.

Comment: Exactly which cost are you trying to avoid here?  It will always cost money to write a document.  That can't be avoided.  The code you're showing does not read any documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the [API Reference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/index.html) for the Cloud Firestore Node.js Client, the [`set()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#set) method will return a Promise that resolves with a [`WriteResult`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/WriteResult.html) which "wraps the write time set by the Firestore servers".

AFAIK, you will not pay for receiving this response. As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing?authuser=0#operations):

> Charges for writes and deletes are straightforward. For writes, each
>   set or update operation counts a single write.

So you will only pay for the write operation (the call to `set()`).

---

Note that with the JavaScript SDK the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) methods behaves slightly differently, as it returns a `Promise<void>`. But the pricing model is the same (each set operation counts a single write).